# How to combine R code with shell code?

Tags: r, bash, unix

I want to compare the speed of matrix multiplication using different number of cores. I want to write a for loop on number of cores in shell code. But the actual computation is done in R. So it's a mix of bash shell code and R code. Something like the following

```
for p in {1..8}
do
    export OMP_NUM_THREADS = p

    ## R code for matrix multiplication ##

done
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: There are numerous techniques to run an R script from the command line. I suggest you write an R script in a separate file, and call it from your bash script with `Rscript --vanilla script.R`.

Answer (score 1):

`Rscript` is *the* command to do just that. Make you R script executable and put at the 1st line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

After that, you can treat it as any other program in the system, calling it from `bash` and whatever else.